# Why my data value is not equal to my string?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use make an AJAX request that returns a data in text format. This AJAX request will query a PHP page that returns either `Success` or `Failed`.

When I `console.log` the response I get `Success`. However when I compare it to the `Success` string, it tells me that they don't have the same value. Why?

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('verificationConnexionAgence.php', {
      identifiant: $("#identifiant").val(),
      motDePasse: $("#motDePasse").val()
    }, function(data) {
      $str1 = "Success";
      console.log(data);
      console.log($str1);

      if ($str1 == data) {
        console.log("EQUAL");
      } else {
        console.log("NO EQUAL")
      }

      if (data == 'Success') {
        $("#resultat").html("<p>Vous avez été connecté avec succès !</p>");
      } else {
        $("#resultat").html("<p>Erreur lors de la connexion...</p>");
      }
    }, 'text');
  });
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: To better debug, try this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` and `console.log(JSON.stringify($str1));`  That will show any white space differences.

Comment: I know that's not the best solution I've chosen ! I try with .trim and it works ! Thanks Rory McCrossan ! I always get stuck on little mistakes like this...

Comment: One of the most important lessons I learned as a developer was the art of debugging.  With l"little mistakes like this" -- Do everything you can to accurately check that values are what you think they are.  In other languages I'll even do things like `Serial.print("[" + myvariable + "]");` to check for whitespace.. things like that.

Answer (score 0):

The common problem when returning a plaintext response from an AJAX call is the unintentional whitespace that's often included and will mean that the direct comparison fails. You can see this is the problem here because the log, as shown in your picture, puts the output of `data` on a new line.

The short term fix for this is to use `trim()` before making the comparison to remove that whitespace:

```js
$.post('verificationConnexionAgence.php', {
  identifiant: $("#identifiant").val(),
  motDePasse: $("#motDePasse").val()
}, function(data) {
  data = data.trim(); // remove the whitespace
  if (data == 'Success') {
    console.log("EQUAL");
    $("#resultat").html("<p>Vous avez été connecté avec succès !</p>");
  } else {
    console.log("NO EQUAL")
    $("#resultat").html("<p>Erreur lors de la connexion...</p>");
  }
}, 'text');
```

The better solution is to return data in a serialised format, such as XML or JSON, so that whitespace has no bearing on the values sent/received in the request.